# Android Function to return an array directly into variables

Tags: java, android, arrays, variable-assignment

I saw that javascript has something similar.
Is it possible to do something like this in Android?
I know how to do it with array names, my question is about returning and assigning directly from the variables that compose the arrays.

```js
private int[] calcHead() {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    // Do stuff
    return {i, j, k};     <-- is this possible? (I am getting error: "The Method must return a result of type int[]")
}

private void otherFunc(){
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    {a, b, c} = calcHead();   <-- is this possible?
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a rather basic question:
Anyway :

```
public int[] foo() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    return new int[]{i,j,k};
}
```

Comment: Thank you, silly questions are the most difficult to google. Please can you answer the other half of the question (the assignment to multiple variables at once), so I credit you with the answer?

Comment: I did not mean as an insult to you. I answered. Can you please explain the "other half"?

Comment: No insult taken! This forum is sometimes for silly questions too, if you cannot find the answer reasonably fast by searching yourself. The other half is: can I do something like **{a,b,c} = calcHead( )**, _see in the question body_

Comment: unfortunately the other part is not doable ):

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the second part of the question, instead of

```
{a, b, c} = calcHead();
```

you can do

```
a = b = c = calcHead();
```

although its not very elegant it would assign the return value to each variable...

Hope that helps!